# JOptionPane message does not show when entering the wrong value

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
 @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      
      if(e.getSource() == back){
       frame.dispose();
         home h = new home();
      }
     
           
      //rent button
      
      if(e.getSource() == rent){
            double money = 0;
            money = Double.parseDouble(txtinsertmoney.getText());
            
            try{
               if(blackadam.isSelected()){
               money = money - 1009.00;
               }
          
               if(up.isSelected()){
               money = money - 212.00; 
               }
            
               if(terminator.isSelected()){
               money = money - 220.00; 
               }
            
               if(justiceleague.isSelected()){
               money = money - 1100.00;
               }
            
               if(yourname.isSelected()){
               money = money - 1200;
               }
            
               if(starwars.isSelected()){
               money = money - 275;
               }
               if(demonslayer.isSelected()){
               money = money - 1100;
               }
               if(madmax.isSelected()){
               money = money - 825;
               }
               if(topgun.isSelected()){
               money = money - 220;
               }
               if(predator.isSelected()){
               money = money - 400;
               }
               if(nul.isSelected()){
               money = money - 220;
               }
               
               else{
               txtchange.setText(Double.toString(money));
               }
               
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"ERROR","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }
            
      }
```

I am trying to display a JOptionPane when entering a String value instead of double. It should pop out with a displayed message as "ERROR" but it does not show. I am also using a try and catch method. ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` is never executed because no exception is thrown! Even if a non-numeric value is entered! Why? Because `parseDouble` has to be in the `try` block and not before it...